# VGG: order of categories?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, caffe, imagenet, vgg-net

I'm using VGG-16 network trained on ILSVRC with Fast-RCNN.

You can get a 1000-dimensional matrix for probability of each of 1,000 classes in ILSVRC.

However, I can't find out which column in the matrix corresponds to which class.

For example, I'd like to know whether final_prob[2] corresponds to human or car.

There are list of classes for ILSVRC each year (http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2014/browse-synsets)

but the matrix doesn't seem to be in that order.

Where can I find out how the entries in the matrix are mapped to the classes?

Comment: Which VGG model are you using?  Did you train it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using one of the pre-trained models in Caffe, run `data/ilsvrc12/get_ilsvrc_aux.sh` and then the list of names of classes will be in `data/ilsvrc12/synset_words.txt`.  This is in the same order as the 1000-dimensional output of the model.